# TYPO3 how to add css class to predefined submit button

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-form

We are building a form in TYPO3 by setting up the form definition with yaml configuration `ourform.form.yaml`.

We know how to add a custom label to the predefined submit button like this `renderingOptions.submitButtonLabel` but cannot figure out how to add a custom class to that element as there is no configuration key for that?

Also I was not able to find a frontend template to override.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve and why a CSS selector like `[id^="form-identifier"] [type="submit"]` does not work?

Comment: our customer wants an easy way to track the clicks via analytics

Comment: Then by all means use JavaScript for that. No need to change the form output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the Fluid partial `Form/Navigation.html`.

There you can set the classes for the different buttons in the form (navigate through different steps and/or submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont even need to overwrite `Form/Navigation.html` because the parent css class `.btn-group` should contain a `.submit` class already that you can target (only if its the last step).